# Change the Outlook folder that a linked table in Acccess is pointing to using VBA

Tags: vba, ms-access, outlook, linked-tables

I have an Access 365 application with a linked table containing emails from a given Outlook folder. I want the user to be able to change the folder that this linked table is connected to from within the application. My code opens the TableDef and changes the .Connect property to the new connection string.

However when I run tdf.RefreshLink I get error 3011: The Microsoft Access database engine could not find the object 'Outlook_Emails'.

My code is as follows:

```
Dim olApp As Outlook.Application
Dim olSession As Outlook.Namespace
Dim olStartFolder As Outlook.Folder

Dim db As DAO.Database

Dim strConnect As String
Dim strMAPILEVEL As String
Dim strTABLE As String
Dim strFolderPath As String
Dim intSplit1 As Integer
Dim intSplit2 As Integer
Dim tdf As DAO.TableDef

Set db = CurrentDb
Set olApp = New Outlook.Application
Set olSession = olApp.GetNamespace("MAPI")

'Pick folder to link to
Set olStartFolder = olSession.PickFolder

'Check to make sure user didn't cancel PickFolder dialog.
If Not (olStartFolder Is Nothing) Then
    'Check Selected folder is a Mail folder
    If olStartFolder.DefaultItemType <> 0 Then
        MsgBox "not a mail folder"
        Exit Sub
    End If
    
    'Relink Outlook table to that folder
    Set tdf = db.TableDefs("Outlook_Emails")
    
    'generate new Connect string
    strFolderPath = olStartFolder.FolderPath
    intSplit1 = InStrRev(strFolderPath, "\", , vbTextCompare)
    strTABLE = Mid(strFolderPath, intSplit1 + 1)
    
    strMAPILEVEL = Mid(strFolderPath, 3, intSplit1 - 3)
    intSplit2 = InStr(strMAPILEVEL, "\")
    strMAPILEVEL = Left(strMAPILEVEL, intSplit2 - 1) & "|" & Mid(strMAPILEVEL, intSplit2) & "\"
    
    strConnect = "Outlook 9.0;MAPILEVEL=" & strMAPILEVEL & ";PROFILE=Outlook;TABLETYPE=0;TABLENAME=" & strTABLE & ";COLSETVERSION=12.0;DATABASE=C:\Users\" & Environ("USERNAME") & "\AppData\Local\Temp\;TABLE=" & strTABLE
    
    tdf.Connect = strConnect
    tdf.RefreshLink
End If
```

Thanks as always for any help,

Jim

Comment: If table link does not exist, I get error on `Set tdf =`: "not in this collection". If table link is already established I get error on `strMAPILEVEL =`: "Invalid procedure or argument". Can't get to the Refresh.

Comment: Worked past that now I get your error. I have code that refreshes table links when I move db to another computer. However, table names are not different, just the file path. Could be this is issue with your code. You are changing folder name, not just computer file path. This is more than a link "refresh". Probably have to delete and recreate link when source folder changes.

Comment: Review https://www.access-programmers.co.uk/forums/threads/linking-an-outlook-folder-with-vba.291562/

Comment: Thanks June7. I think you are right, I also had code which relinked and refreshed the links for tables linking to another database, never had any problems. I am now working on the basis that you cannot change the table being linked to, so deleting the link and creating a new one each time.